# 301 Redirect Subpages to Parent Page in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My website pages having subpages that have subpages of their own.

```
http://mysite.com/rookie/1/
   http://mysite.com/rookie/1/1/
   http://mysite.com/rookie/1/2/
   http://mysite.com/rookie/1/3/
   http://mysite.com/rookie/1/4/
   http://mysite.com/rookie/1/5/
```

Is it possible to redirect the subpages of the subpages or the grandchild pages to their respective parent page using .htaccess?

In the example above,  I want to redirect the following URLs'

```
http://mysite.com/rookie/1/1/
http://mysite.com/rookie/1/2/
http://mysite.com/rookie/1/3/
http://mysite.com/rookie/1/4/
http://mysite.com/rookie/1/5/
```

to `http://mysite.com/rookie/1/`

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score -1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have placed the code in my .htaccess and still it won't redirect the subpages to their parent page. I also tried this (RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) mysite.com/$1/$2) but its affecting all directories in my wordpress blog such as the http://www.mysite.com/wp-content/themes/mytheme/style.css.